# Kotlin - EditText in Inflated View keyboard show on back with black opacity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I inflated popup view with below code
but the problem is keyboard is shown backof popup

```
 val inflater = it.context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater?
            val menuPopup = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.popup_search_new_cosmetics,null)

            val popup = PopupWindow(menuPopup, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, false)
            popup.showAtLocation(menuPopup, Gravity.CENTER,0,0)
            val imgClose = menuPopup.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageClose)
            menuPopup.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageClose)
            recycler = menuPopup.findViewById(R.id.editProductPage)

            showKeyboard(menuPopup.findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch),this)


private fun showKeyboard(mEtSearch: EditText, context: Context) {
    mEtSearch.requestFocus()
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use Alert dialog...

Use this code. Your problem will be solved

```
popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```